# Weird local domain behaviour

Tags: network, macos, hosts, domain

I just clean installed mavericks on my mac and local domains i use for web development still work. Surely clean install wipes the host file, so how is this possible? Its not really a problem, i am just wondering how its possible!

Current hosts file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Comment: Were your local domains previously listed in the host file?

Comment: yeah, like 127.0.0.1 jf.co.uk

Comment: Now a few days have passed, do the domains still resolve locally?

Comment: Yeah they do, i've come back from uni as well so its not my router

Comment: It is unlikely to answer the question but you may want to reset the DNS cache: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5343